# Sorting table on date with ''

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting

So I have the following usecase where i have dates and empty strings in a table.

The problem is that the sorting doesn't do what I expected.
Normally with strings it will put the empty string on the top or the bottom of the sort.

But with date it push them in between.

```
json = ['01-01-2018', '', '04-03-2018', '03-03-2018', '', '04-03-2018', '03-03-2018'];
this.json.sort((obj1: string, obj2: string) => {
  if (new Date(obj1) > new Date(obj2)) { return 1; }
  if (new Date(obj1) < new Date(obj2)) { return -1; }
  return 0;
});
```

This will result in: `01-01-2018,,03-03-2018,04-03-2018,,03-03-2018,04-03-2018`.

Here is a simple stackblitz of it:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y45la8)

I have tried to make it a number a sort it. But then still the issue with the empty string stays. Does any1 have a solution how to solve this?

Comment: *But then still the issue with the empty string stays* What is the issue with empty? What is the result you want?

Comment: Never a good idea to parse date strings like this, especially if they don't follow the [supported format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). Behavior will be highly implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check to see if the value is convertable to a date/time type and then return either -1 or 1 (depending on where you want them located) if they are not.

```
json = ['01-01-2018', '', '04-03-2018', '03-03-2018', '', '04-03-2018', '03-03-2018'];
this.json.sort((obj1: string, obj2: string) => {
  if (obj1 === obj2) { return 0; } // if they are the same then no need to convert these instances to Date types later, just return 0
  if (!obj1) { return 1; } // thruthy check
  if (!obj2) { return -1; } // thruthy check

  if (new Date(obj1) > new Date(obj2)) { return 1; }
  if (new Date(obj1) < new Date(obj2)) { return -1; }
  return 0;
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wijuma)

```
// Initial array
'01-01-2018', '', '', '', '04-03-2018', '03-03-2018', '', '04-03-2018', '03-03-2018'

// Sorted array
'01-01-2018', '03-03-2018', '03-03-2018', '04-03-2018', '04-03-2018', '', '', '', ''
```

---

On a side note I recommend [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) instead of javascript's `Date`. It is much more powerful and you can include a format string with the value you are passing in so the string is parsed correctly.

Comment: This should work I tried this out in my code and it doesn't work.
I edited my stackblitz and it's working as expected.
But in my code it isn't I will have to look what's the differents. cheers

Comment: Ohh I tried moment.js indead but in the end I still have the same issue.

Comment: @Swoox - your updated stackblitz works ok for me. Change the html template code to this: `<div *ngFor="let items of json">{{items[0].date ? items[0].date : '&lt;empty&gt;'}}</div>`, does that display the expected results?

Comment: Yes it does but my real code doesn't, I just have to figure out why.

Comment: The problem was I put a dd-mm-yyyy date in the new Date() it expect mm-dd-yyyy...

Comment: @Swoox glad you got to the bottom of it. That is one of the reasons I prefer `momentjs`, you can specify the format string (in this case `DD-MM-YYYY`) when you create a new moment instance so you are not dependent on the culture (of the browser) in which the script is running.

Comment: The moment.js need iso format. It will give a deprecate warning.

Comment: @Swoox - see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xgnewy), you need to provide the [format string as the 2nd parameter](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and that should not cause a deprecated warning.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the values are set:

```
 sort(){
    this.json.sort((obj1: string, obj2: string) => {
      if (!obj1 ||!obj2) {return -1}
      if (new Date(obj1)> new Date(obj2)) { return 1; }
      if (new Date(obj1)< new Date(obj2)) { return -1; }

      return 0;
    });
  }
```

result:

```
,,01-01-2018,03-03-2018,03-03-2018,04-03-2018,04-03-2018
```